# Как правильнее: свой или ваш?

Tags: выбор-слов, выбор-варианта

На рассмотрении два варианта:

1. > Ознакомьтесь с другими вопросами по метке или задайте ваш вопрос.
2. > Ознакомьтесь с другими вопросами по метке или задайте свой вопрос.

Какой использовать предпочтительнее и почему?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Возвратно-притяжательное местоимение "свой" может относиться ко всем лицам, поэтому выражения "ваши вопросы" и "свои вопросы" в данном случае  **синонимичны**, соответственно,  **могут быть использованы оба варианта**.

В то же время в некоторых случаях надо учитывать ситуацию: **ваш вопрос ― это тот, который связан с вами**, который вы озвучиваете, а **свой вопрос** ― это ваш собственный/авторский вопрос, составленный лично вами.

Так как здесь ряд уже имеющихся вопросов противопоставлен  другим возможным вопросам, то второй вариант кажется более информативным:  **Ознакомьтесь с другими вопросами по метке или задайте свой вопрос** (= которого там нет).